# Getting a rolling release just right and then freezing it: a good idea?

Tags: administration, software-updates, stability, rolling-release

I really like how rolling releases offer the latest versions of everything, because sometimes that is important. However, once I have things working well, I am not that anxious to keep updating to the latest.

Is it a sensible strategy to "freeze" my installation of an rolling distro like Arch and then only manually update the kernel and base packages a few times a year? The install in question does nothing except host VMs for PCI passthrough, share storage to those VMs, and handle online backup. So I shouldn't be needing to add new upgrades unless I decide I need some feature in a new version. Ideally I could identify bugfix-only patches and only do those unless I had a specific reason to do otherwise.

Is this a sensible strategy?

Comment: Depending on the software, you might not even get a bugfix-only update - the distro may well have moved on to a new release.

Comment: That is called "enterprise" or "stable" release. Bonus is that a lot of others do the selecting/stabilizing/bug fixing for you. And the setup is trivially repeatable.